# windows batch compare then skip utf ∩╗┐ in first line of file

Tags: windows, batch, utf-8, string

I would like list lines of file in batch and, in case of UTF file, skip "∩╗┐" characters in first line.

```
@echo off  
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
 set /a count+=1
 set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
) 
echo "!Line[1]:~0!"
echo "!Line[1]:~0,3!"
if "!Line[1]:~0,3!" == "∩╗┐" set "Line[1]=!Line[1]:~3!"
echo "!Line[1]:~0!"
echo "!Line[1]:~3!"

Pause>nul
```

but "∩╗┐" characters are not comparable in expression:

```
if "!Line[1]:~0,3!" == "∩╗┐" set "Line[1]=!Line[1]:~3!"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `list.txt` is saved in [UTF-8 encoding with byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark) and `∩╗┐` characters are appearance of [UTF-8 Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) bytes  in `CP437` encoding (see example below as well).

> Non-UTF-8 software may show the BOM as three garbage characters, e.g.
>   `"ï»¿"` in software interpreting the document as ISO 8859-1 or
>   Windows-1252, and `"∩╗┐"` if interpreted as code page 437. This is an
>   example of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), the output of garbled text when text is
>   decoded using an unintended character encoding.

I'd guess that your script is saved in *co-called "ANSI"* (CP1252) encoding so use `ï»¿` instead:

```
if "!Line[1]:~0,3!" == "ï»¿" set "Line[1]=!Line[1]:~3!"
```

---

Example; (added an instance of code page 1250 with resultant mojibake `ď»ż`):

```
chcp 1250
type D:\bat\SU\list1545301_UTF8-BOM.txt
chcp 1252
type D:\bat\SU\list1545301_UTF8-BOM.txt
chcp 437
type D:\bat\SU\list1545301_UTF8-BOM.txt
```

> ```
> Active code page: 1250
> ď»żthis is line1
> this is line2
>
> Active code page: 1252
> ï»¿this is line1
> this is line2
>
> Active code page: 437
> ∩╗┐this is line1
> this is line2
> ```